# javascript - blocking a set of dates in a date input, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, block

I'm doing an upgrade to a customer's website and I found the following challenge:

This customer has a reservation system composed of two date input tags to determine the dates he/she is entering a hotel room. I know there's some jQuery and even pure javascript-driven plug-ins (like the DHTMLX suite or even the jQuery EasyUI controls) which do wonders in this sense, but I would like to know if it could be possible to add date blocking functionality into a plain `<input type="date">` tag.

So far, I've got to add predefined dates using a `<datalist>` tag and using it with the date input with the `list` attribute, but that's about it.

Is it possible to block dates with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like support for `<input type="date">` is still [not solid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/#compat-desktop). I was interested to learn that this feature is coming, though. I found [this article](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#dates-and-times) quite helpful, and its examples use Opera for its examples, which gives you a sense of what is coming.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwyF5/) containing a data input. For me it renders as a plain text field :(

```
<input id="startdate" name="startdate" min="2012-01-01" max="2013-01-01" type="date">
```

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML5 version doesn't work for you (it didn't for me), you can always use jQueryUI's Datepicker:

```
<input type="text" id="example-date">
```

And then in your script:

```
$('#example-date').datepicker({ minDate: +1 });
```

This sets the minimum selectable date to a day from the current day.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date">
```

should support attributes min, max, and value